# python copytree with negated ignore pattern

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to use python to copy a tree of files/directories.

is it possible to use copytree to copy everything that ends in foo?

There is an ignore_patterns patterns function, can I give it a negated regular expression? Are they supported in python?

eg.

copytree(src, dest, False, ignore_pattern('!*.foo'))
Where ! means NOT anything that ends in foo.
thanks.

Comment: '(.*\.foo)' is the right expression to get all words that have .foo. (?!...) as seen in the re module documentation[1] can be used to negate expressions, but I couldn't make it work...
1- http://docs.python.org/library/re.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`shutil.copytree` has an [`ignore` keyword](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree). `ignore` can be set to any callable. Given the directory being visited and a list of its contents, the callable should return a sequence of directory and filenames to be ignored.

For example:

```
import shutil
def ignored_files(adir,filenames):
    return [filename for filename in filenames if not filename.endswith('foo')]

shutil.copytree(source, destination, ignore=ignored_files)
```

Comment: I just wanted to point out that [unutbu's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2821871/1177225) will not traverse nested directories unless they also end in "foo". Instead, you'll probably want to only perform the endswith check if not os.path.isdir(filename).

Comment: the `os.path.isdir` should be called on `os.path.join(adir, filename)`

Answer (score 6):

Building on unutbu's answer.  The following takes a list of all files, then *removes* the ones matched by "ignore_patterns", then returns that as a list of files to be *ignored*.  That is, it does a double negation to only copy the files you want.

```
import glob, os, shutil

def copyonly(dirpath, contents):
    return set(contents) - set(
        shutil.ignore_patterns('*.py', '*.el')(dirpath, contents),
        )

shutil.copytree(
    src='.',
    dst='temp/',
    ignore=copyonly,
    )
print glob.glob('temp/*')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def documentation(format):
    call(['make', format, '-C', DOC_SOURCE_DIR])

    if (os.path.exists(DOC_DIR)):
        shutil.rmtree(DOC_DIR)

    ignored = ['doctrees']
    shutil.copytree('{0}/build/'.format(DOC_SOURCE_DIR), DOC_DIR, ignore=shutil.ignore_patterns(*ignored))
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on top of [@unutbu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2821871/1328576) and [@johntellsall](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2822020/1328576), this solution also works recursively.

```py
def inverse_ignore_patterns(*patterns: str):
    def _inverse_ignore_patterns(path, names):
        ignored_names = set(names)
        for pattern in patterns:
            ignored_names -= set(fnmatch.filter(names, pattern))

        # Keep folders
        ignored_names -= {
            name for name in ignored_names
            if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path, name))
        }
        return ignored_names

    return _inverse_ignore_patterns
```

One downside is that  will create empty directories if they don't contain any matching files. You can easily fix that with:

```py
def rm_empty_folders(rootdir: str):
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(rootdir, topdown=False):
        if not os.listdir(dirpath):
            os.rmdir(dirpath)
```

Use as:

```py
copytree(src, dest, False, inverse_ignore_patterns("*.foo"))
rm_empty_folders(dest)
```